# crm update prevalidation plugin can't get entity

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a plugin for crm 2011. Prevalidation on update with a PreImage. I can get the PreImage just fine using the context. by doing:

```
var preImage = context.PreImage.ToEntity<EntityName>();
```

This gives me the preImage so without the changed values. Now I try to get my entity with changed values by using the context.

```
var update = context.GetEntity.ToEntity<EntityName();
```

However I don't get any data.

How do I get the updated data? Anyone can help me and tell me why this doesn't work. I hope this is enough code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following code will help you.

```
protected void ExecuteYourPlugin(LocalPluginContext localContext)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext pluginContext = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
    // Get Target Entity
    var updateEntity = (Entity)pluginContext.InputParameters["Target"];

    // Get PreImage Entity
    var preEntity = (Entity)localContext.PluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages["PreImage"];

    // Is in Update
    if(localContext.PluginExecutionContext.MessageName.ToLower() == "update")
    {
        var fieldName = string.Empty;

            // If Contains, Extract value from Target Entity
            if(updateEntity.Contains("new_fieldname"))
            {
                // Cast the fields according their type
                fieldName = updateEntity["new_fieldname"].toString();
            }
            // Else extract the value from preImage
            else if(preEntity .Contains("new_fieldname"))
            {
                // Cast the fields according their type
                fieldName = preEntity["new_fieldname"].toString();
            }
    }
}
```